# control the expiration of session

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

sometimes after some minutes i have to refresh browser to get my web application with JSF work again, maybe it's a problem of **web.xml**

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

after 30 minutes the session will exist when there's no user interaction with the session. After this period the session will be invalidated.
so i want that i control the session in my code (til the user logout) not with minutes in **web.xml**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want your session to never expire. If that's what you want you just need to set session-timeout parameter to 0. In other words change 30 to 0 in your web.xml file.